# ErrorHandlerAttribute and migration from MVC 2 to MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have migrated website from MVC 2 to MVC 3 and now faced with problem that my error handler attribute is not working

I'm marking my method as

```
[HttpPost]
[CampaignRequestErrorHandler]
public ActionResult Finish(T request)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return GoToCreateView(request);
}            
try
....
```

I added my CampaignRequestErrorHandler to Route filters and it worked but I need to enable only method scope error handling.

Please help me if you have some idea where is the bug

Comment: Problem solved. CampaignRequestErrorHandler attribute should be used for action methods or controllers. Instead I used it only on usual methods. Also customErrors must be "on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know that ASP.NET MVC3 can use global filters to handle errors.
You can read more [here](http://colinmackay.co.uk/blog/2011/05/02/custom-error-pages-and-error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-3-2/), [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Cmiller/archive/2011/03/16/asp_net_mvc_3_errorhandling_and_customerrors.aspx) and [here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx).